# C# An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, .net

Even though I'm checking whether the map already contains the key just before I add it, I receive this error..

```
if (ShortBuffer.ContainsKey(GetTuple(data))) return;
ShortBuffer.Add(GetTuple(data),                 <----- ERROR OCCURS HERE
    new Tuple<Timer, int, bool, Data>(
        new Timer(Convert.ToInt32(Ini.ReadValue("intervals", "clientbuffershort"))), 0, false, data));
```

The GetTuple method:

```
private static Tuple<string, string, string> GetTuple(Data data)
{
    return new Tuple<string, string, string>(data.AucxisErrorId, data.ClientId, data.Area);
}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Is your app multi-threaded...

Comment: No it isn't, that's why I don't get it

Comment: Then we need the code to reproduce the problem in order to answer your question. (Short but complete code sample)

Comment: You try using a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) to make sure it's not a threading problem.

Comment: You dont have some parallel foreach or something going on? it sure sounds like a thread issue. - Would it not be easier to create a variable of the "GetTuple(data)" contents, so it only does that once?

Comment: Not that it matters to your question but you should consider taking this out `GetTuple(data)` and calling it once. I can't reproduce your problem is a single threaded app though. Something funky must be going on. Is your `Data` structure immutable? Can it be that it's changing between calls (as in calls to properties have a side-effect)?

Answer (score 1):

First of all the GetTuple method returns a new instance every time you call it. It might contain the same data but they are still different objects. So the first step I would do is change the code to this:

```
var tuple = GetTuple(data);
if (ShortBuffer.ContainsKey(tuple)) return;

ShortBuffer.Add(tuple, new Tuple<Timer, int, bool, Data>(
    new Timer(Convert.ToInt32(Ini.ReadValue("intervals", "clientbuffershort"))), 0, false));
```

This makes sure you are atleast comparing and adding the exact same object to the map.

Second make sure the Tuple class implements the `IEquatable<T>` interface. This way you can be sure the contents of the Tuple objects are compared and not the memory address of where the objects are stored (since they differ from each other). More information on how to implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `Tuple<T1, T2, ...>` is a .NET class and cannot be changed. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Agreed, now I know ;). And the positive thing is that it already implement IStructuralEquatable (which in turn derives from IEquatable). So you are good here.